# How do I remove the local history a repository without changing the remote?

Tags: git, git-extensions

I use Git Extensions to manage the local repository (remote is in a Microsoft TFS server).

When you initially clone the repository to the local machine, you have an option of not downloading the whole history of that repo, which saves a lot of space. Over time, however, every commit keeps accumulating in your local machine, using up a lot of space.

How do I clean up the history of commits from the local repository, without affecting the remote one?

Comment: why not delete and re-clone the repo?

Comment: "Over time, however, every commit keeps accumulating in your local machine, using up a lot of space". This is likely not true. Git is pretty efficient with its use of disk space, and you're (probably) storing text.

Comment: …(continuing the previous comment) and don't forget regularly run `git gc --aggressive` to compact the repositories even better.

Answer (score 0):

you can clone a repo with the argument `--depth=n` to only pull the `n` most recent commits. so `git clone --depth=1` will give you a repo with only the latest commit and no log, or something like `git clone --depth=100` will give you the 100 most recent commits locally, without the bloat of the entire history.

Comment: You can make a local clone and then just copy over .git/config, and voila

Comment: Can I do this with an existing repo? Or deleting and cloning again is the only way?